20 kHz full bridge inverter

I have designed high frequency full bridge inverter 20 kHz. I am using TLP250 as my gate driver and 10N60 MOSFETS. The problem is that it works fine at frequencies up to 2 kHz.

At high frequency the duty cycle varies the width of the wave but it is not able to switch off fast enough so it is always on as shown in the picture. My doubt is that it need any kind of filter but I do not know how to put it.

I have posted the schematic.

How are you powering your MOSFET drivers?

Why does the schematic show IR2101s? Are the pin names or numbers supposed to be representative? -- asking readers to double-check these things costs time they could better spend reviewing the question or writing an answer. || There are many connectors/pins in the schematic; to what are they connected?

MOSFET drivers are connected from external power supply of 15 volt

X1 pin is output and X2 is input pin

X5,X8,X3,X10 are the input 15 volt for the gate drivers

Is there a load connected?

It's unclear why you use the IR2101 like this. The datasheet showes that it should be completely different...

Yes resistance of 1k ohm is connected

IR2101 is a place holder. I am using TLP250 instead

Can you please show two tracks on the scope, one X1-1 vs. X2-2 and one X1-2 vs. X2-2?
